# parted can't have overlapping partitions

Tags: ubuntu, parted

for debug purposes i need to extend my disk to all unallocated space, for example

my full disk size is 931.5GB and i have the following partitions

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0 107.5G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0   3.8G  0 part [SWAP]
```

so my /dev/sda2 partiton is less than 931.5GB and i need to increase this partition with parted command to have more espace

unallocated space is : 819.72GB (see with gparted)
parted /dev/sda resizepart 2 500GB
but this command returns the following error :

```
 Can't have overlapping partitions
```

i am doing all this with a live usb in order to do not have mounted /dev/sda, the curious thing is that parted allow me to shrink the partition, i mean this

```
 parted /dev/sda resizepart 2 50GB
```

one more thing, if i can get the solution to this problem i would like to use the option -s in order to automate this process with some bash scripts

This is the output for fdisk -l command

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: C680462D-DE3F-4A97-B2A2-50226E7F9668

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1050624 226453503 225402880 107.5G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  226453504 234440703   7987200   3.8G Linux swap
```

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you remove the SWAP partition temporarily. I can't tell because I can't "see with gparted"

Comment: how can i do that ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the output of `sudo fdisk -l` so that we can see where your partitions begin and end.

Comment: done, please check the output for fdisk -l in the question

Comment: Checked and answered.

Comment: Why do you want to automate this process? Do you have a number of drives with the same partition layout?

Comment: yes, actually i have a the following system, i have a lot of images created by clonezilla in a server and i downloaded all those images every day, so this images has been created with the swap partition in /dev/sda3 next to / root directory, so when a image is downloaded i need to automate this because some test needs of full hard drive space

Comment: This sounds feasible but some math is required. Would it be acceptable to move the swap partition to the end of the disk?

Comment: could be , but i think that in order to fix this issue and not as workaround is have the root partition at the end ? isn't it ?

Comment: There's always more than one way to solve any problem. I don't have the details of your situation. For instance all I know is that you wanted to increase the available space for the file system.  I don't know why you chose `resizepart 2 50GB` I thought the command was `resize minor start end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't grow `/dev/sda2` is your swap partition at `/dev/sda3` is too close to `/dev/sda2` to allow for any growth. Note that your `/dev/sda2` partition starts at sector 226453503 and your swap partition begins at the very next sector 226453504. So in effect you are asking to grow a partition over the following one (a very bad idea, which is why `gparted` does not allow it).

In order to resolve this problem you could move the swap to the tail end of the drive (`gparted` comes to mind) or remove it and add it back after growing `/dev/sda2` (with whatever partitioning tools you are most comfortable with). Sadly I have no suggestions for automating the process as it appears to be situationally dependent. However at least now you know the root cause of your problem.

There's a very similar issue and solution [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_chapter/parted_2.html#SEC30).

Comment: ok, i understand, i'll try this and i'll report back

Comment: that's fix mi issue, i deleted swap partition and then i can grow my partition, thanks a lot

Comment: You might need that swap partition. did you reserve space for it and put it back?

Comment: Your OS may not find the swap partition when its UUID changes or it moves to `sda4`. Best to keep both the same.

Answer (score 0):

Another pretty simple solution for anyone who may encounter this after adding a new boot partition (or any other partition, although may require some more steps) is to sort the partitions using `gdisk` before trying to resize via parted:

```
gdisk /dev/sdX
Command (? for help): s
```

After that, parted did not present the overlapping partitions error.

Comment: How is this a solution? The partitions are already in order of increasing start sector. This shouldn't change anything. Furthermore, even if the order was different, changing the order of the partition entries would not change the fact that the swap partition blocks the OS partition from growing into the unallocated space.

Comment: That is not always true. In my case, I had to convert the partition table from MBR to GPT. An additional boot partition was added at the beginning of the drive sectors, most likely due to a malfunction of the conversion or simply because GPT is designed to support dynamic resizing and reconfiguration of partitions, which means you can create, resize, and delete partitions without the same restrictions imposed by MBR where everything had to be in order from the start. A simple sort did the trick for me and stopped the overlap of the partitions.

Comment: Without knowing what exactly `gdisk` did to your disk, we cannot tell whether (1) it actually changed, as you believe, the start and/or end points of one or more partitions to fix the overlap, potentially resizing filesystem(s) or making other adjustments, (2) `gdisk` wrongly reports that there is an overlap if the start sector of a partition is earlier than the end sector of the previous partition and sorting the order of partition entries allowed it to see that no partitions overlap, or (3) there is an overlap but sorting the entries triggered a bug so `gdisk` no longer can see the overlap.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To automate Elder's answer for a large number of clonzilla images with different disk sizes and partition sizes and assuming the basic layout EFI + OS + Swap is always the same and the OS is not hibernated on swap, the most difficult part is to move the swap partition to the end of the disk. Gparted does not seem to accept positions relative to the end (using negative start/end numbers). You'd have to process the output of `parted print` to find out how large the disk is and to automate the calculation of the start and end positions to use in the `mkpart` command of gparted (and align the start of the partition as desired, e.g. at multiples of 2048 sectors). You'd need some programming, e.g. as a shell script.